# Displaying DateTime picker instead of Date picker in ASP .NET MVC 5.1/HTML 5 specific

Tags: c#, razor, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I write application in ASP .NET MVC 5.1

I have a field:

```
  [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

and then in View

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

which translates to:

[image]

if I just change annotiations above property in model to:

```
    [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

I don't get any picker displayed. If I change them to:

```
 [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
 [DataType(DataType.Time)]
```

there is only hh:mm to choose from.

**Question:** Displaying DateTime picker instead of Date picker in ASP .NET MVC 5.1. I am asking for ASP .NET 5.1 HTML 5 specific solution.

Answer (score 10):

Your requirements are pretty *picky*...

Specifying the attribute `Datatype` for a field, will generate an `input` having as `type` the attribute specified. That's why when you add `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`, the input generated will be a date picker, but if you add `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]`, the input will be of type `datetime`, thus why you don't get any picker displayed. Why? Because a few years ago, the browsers supporting input `datetime` decided to stop supporting it and W3C removed this feature due to lack of implementation.

However, not so long ago, some browser vendors started supporting again `datetime-local` which is back on the draft. As of now, the latest versions of `Chrome`, `Opera` and `Microsoft Edge` support it.

One solution would be to use the BootStrap or the jQuery Datetime Picker as Ajay Kumar suggested.

Another one would be, if you don't mind the few supporting browsers, to use `datetime-local`. Like this for instance:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { type = "datetime-local"})
```

Comment: I don't see this a picky in the slightest. Just because something has not been implemented doesn't mean it's picky to ask for it. I think it's ridiculous that there is no date and time picker. It's a standard control on phone OS now, why not browsers?

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. I was mainly saying that for the pun

Comment: Ah sorry. I'm so ashamed. I should have taken more _time_ reading your post

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this date picker because of html5 and browser supporting html5.
Possible options :

- [BootStrap datetime picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
- [jQuery Datetime Picker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

Comment: I am looking for ASP .NET MVC 5.1 and HTML 5 solution. No JavaScript, JQuery etc. Is there any other solution than install Safari?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min_date  http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_datetime  http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_time

Comment: Your bootstrap link is for a date picker, not date and time, and so is your w3schools link.

Answer (score 5):

Add in object definition:

```
public class EditViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss}")]
    [Display(Name = "Registed Date")]
    public DateTime RegistedDate { get; set; }
}
```

in .cshtml add as:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistedDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistedDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "datetime-local" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistedDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Brilliant!  I've been trying to figure this out off and on for months!

Comment: Great solution for those not trying to use jQuery UI or some other plugin. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution was slightly different. Although it does use javascript/jQuery to accomplish. I went with the Fact if you use the data annotation

```
[Display(Name = "The Display Name")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss tt}")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime DateTimeFieldName { get; set; }
```

Now you have to have jqueryUI scripts and CSS included on the page(or in a bundle). In Javascript :

```
$(function () {//DOM ready code
    // Get data-annotations that are Marked DataType.DateTime and make them jquery date time pickers
    $('input[type=datetime]').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', timeFormat: 'hh:mm', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showAnim: 'slideDown' });
});// END DOM Ready
```

Since the `DataType(DataType.DateTime)` makes a input with the type being datetime. Just use that fact and take all of those and make them date time pickers using jQuery. I have this code that is included in my `_Layout` page bundle.

So now all I have to do is annotate the property in the model and It will show up as a jQuery Date time picker.
You may want to change the defaults for the date time picker. Hope this helps someone out.