# EmailAddress or DataType.Email attribute

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between the `[EmailAddress]` and the `[DataType(DataType.Email)]` attribute?

What is the difference between the `[Phone]` and `[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]` attribute?

```
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Phone]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

and

```
[DataType(DataType.Email)]
public string Email { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Are these the same or is there any difference? What is the difference? Which is the preferred way? When should which be used?

Comment: You have to check it for yourself. Some browsers mat or may not support those types.

Comment: @Yoda: Web browsers don't have native support for `System.ComponentModel` objects (or, well, the .NET Framework) anyway, so it's not really clear what you're saying...

Comment: @David When HTML is generated if you for instance use(and ONLY then) `[DataType[DataType.Date]]` above `DateTime` property the `Html.EditorFor` will generate an HTML element `<.... type="Date" .../>` which will have for intance Chrome support in form of Date picker. If you will not use this annotation it will not happenn. I did not have said anything about native support. Those annotations affect output HTML, the `type=""` part and some of browser will support some types some won't. For instance `DateTime` has been dropped from ALL browsers but you still can use this DateType and in output

Comment: @David HTML it will be present, but you won't get datetime picker from browser like you would for `DataType.Date` or `DataType.Time`.  You can look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765750/displaying-datetime-picker-instead-of-date-picker-in-asp-net-mvc-5-1-html-5-spe

Comment: @Yoda: The question isn't about whether browsers support different output, the question is whether or not these different annotations *emit* different output (or do anything differently).  A browser isn't involved in answering that.  If you're implying that there *is* different output, that's probably worth noting in an answer by identifying the differences.  If you're just saying that "browsers will treat different output differently" then I think that's a given.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`DataTypeAttribute` changes the `type` attribute of the `<input>` elements rendered by MVC.

@David is right that `EmailAddressAttribute` derives from `DataTypeAttribute`, so all functionality you get with `[DataType(DataType.Email)]` is also present when you use `[EmailAddress]`. Both attributes cause MVC to render HTML `<input type="email">` elements.

However, `EmailAddressAttribute` adds server-side validation on top of that. **I.e. there is no server-side validation if you only use `DataTypeAttribute`!** You can easily test your model with each of those attributes. For each of them, you should get client-side validation and it shouldn't be possible to submit the form with invalid email address. However, if you change the `<input>` element type to `text` (via Firebug or whatnot), you will remove that validation and will be able to submit the form with whatever text you like. Then, put a breakpoint in the action invoked by submitting the form and examine the value of `ModelState.IsValid` - when you use `DataTypeAttribute`, it is `true`. When you use `EmailAddressAttribute`, it is `false`. This is because the latter adds some regex-based server-side validation.

Conclusion: you should use `EmailAddressAttribute` et al., otherwise you're not really doing the validation on your end and rely on the client to do it (a Bad Thing™).

Of course you can also use `DataTypeAttribute` and implement your own server-side validation (e.g. because the one in `EmailAddressAttribute` doesn't work for you for whatever reason).

Answer (score -1):

There's probably no difference, other than the static type of the attribute.  Looking at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), classes like `EmailAddressAttribute` and `PhoneAttribute` inherit from `DataTypeAttribute`, so they're likely just convenient delegates to the more generic parent with its properties already set.

Note also that this doesn't really have anything to do with MVC, this is the `System.ComponentModel` functionality.  MVC *uses* it, but doesn't own it.

Comment: This is not correct - `EmailAddressAttribute` does server-side validation. `DataTypeAttribute` doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

As far as their implementation in MVC, I believe that there was a time where EmailAddressAttribute and PhoneAttribute were validation related and would render input type="text" and that the the DataType attributes were rendering related. However after some quick testing that is no longer the case.

They do in fact seem to be different implementations of the same functionality.  They both render as type="email" and both validate email addresses.  The DataType.Email validation is slightly different from the EmailAddressValidation, it does not go through jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js to wire up validation and for that reason I would lean towards the EmailAddressAttribute, but likely there will be no functional difference.

Comment: EmailAddressAttribute does server-side validation. DataTypeAttribute doesn't. This is a fundamental functional difference.