# ModelState.IsValid is always true

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

As is typical in MVC, I have a View, a Model, and a Controller.

The View contains a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <ul class="fieldlist">
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m =>m.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
        </li>
        <li>
            <div Class="row">
                <div Class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

The model looks like this:

```
public class UserAdminUserViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User Database ID"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string Name { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "First Name"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address"), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Telephone Number"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller to receive the updates:

```
[HttpPost,ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult User(UserAdminUserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do something, apply the updates to the database, presumably
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

...but ModelState.IsValid is *always* true. The controller *is* receiving the entered information, but it appears that no validation is taking place. I have tried:

```
TryUpdateModel<UserAdminUserViewModel>(model);
```

and

```
UpdateModel<UserAdminUserViewModel>(model);
```

I'm not sure I see how these would work, but they were the first suggestions I came across. No dice. Still valid regardless of the data in 'model'. I also tried:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateObject(model, new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(model));
```

More promising, but still doesn't work. I also tried the more verbose approach:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext valContext = new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(model, null, null);
List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult> valResults = new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>();
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.TryValidateObject(model, valContext, valResults, true);
foreach(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult result in valResults)
{
    this.ModelState.AddModelError(result.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty, result.ErrorMessage);
}
```

...which also didn't work. 'valResults', which should contain any errors in the state of the model, is never filled; no validation is happening.

Comment: Do you have your the client side jquery.validate, jquery.unobtrusive and jquery.validate.unobtrusive included somewhere in scope to that form?

Comment: Silly though, but you are passing incorrect data as well to test right?!

Comment: I am deliberately entering an incorrect email address, yes.

Comment: So, the problem with incorrect email address?

Comment: @Tom Have you tried using the `[EmailAddress]` attribute for your email address? Thats usually what I use for email address validation and it seems to work find. `DataType.EmailAddress` seems odd to me

Comment: @RossBush That doesn't really matter because server-side validation should still work even if client-side isn't wired up properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this for email validation:

```
@using using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Please see this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994423/emailaddress-or-datatype-email-attribute)

> However, EmailAddressAttribute adds server-side validation on top of
>   that. I.e. there is no server-side validation if you only use
>   DataTypeAttribute!

Comment: [EmailAddress] was the missing component, adding this solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem with incorrect email address, here's the solution:

```
[Email(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
[Required()]
[Display(Name = "Email Address"), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

`DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)` means only how to show textbox on client-side, while `Email` attribute does actual validation.