# Datatype Model validation for Password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

What is the role of `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` in model?
When I'm applying this in my model this will not convert my password into hash format and all passwords are in readable form.

Comment: Please provide some context in order to get a clear picture of the problem.

Comment: I have a page of create user in which user can write there desire password and password save into database, but I want to save that password in unreadable form for this purpose i am using @Html.PasswordFor in view and datatype.password in model but it doesn't work and save password as it is in database

Comment: kindly read my scenario and reply @Bouke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can find about dataType here [EmailAddress or DataType.Email attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994423/emailaddress-or-datatype-email-attribute)

If you want to convert password into hash, you can use SHA256.

This method returns hash, you need to pass password as parameter:

```
public static string Sha256Hash(string value, string salt = default)
        {
            using var sha256Hash = SHA256.Create();
            {
                var hash = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value + salt));

                var builder = new StringBuilder();
                
                for (var i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
                }

                return builder.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: kindly share some sample work