# Creating Common Custom HTML HELPER For Date Time Picker in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is it Possible to combine input Type = Date and input type = Time in One Single Custom Helper. Below is my Short Code

```
TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("input");`enter code here`
tag.Attributes.Add("name", datePickerName);
tag.Attributes.Add("type", "date");
tag.Attributes.Add("value", datePickerValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

//Code For Creating Time
TagBuilder tagTime = new TagBuilder("input");
tagTime.Attributes.Add("name", datePickerName);
tagTime.Attributes.Add("type", "time");
tagTime.Attributes.Add("value", datePickerValue.ToString("HH:mm"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying DateTime picker instead of Date picker in ASP .NET MVC 5.1/HTML 5 specific](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765750/displaying-datetime-picker-instead-of-date-picker-in-asp-net-mvc-5-1-html-5-spe)

Comment: Its Not Duplicate Question............I m Creating a Custom Html Hepler in which i m writing am Above Code in a static method in Static Class....